# i use selenium firefox to download mp4 files with url(example:http://xxxx/xxxx.mp4) always hang?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

i use selenium firefox to download mp4 files with url(example:http://xxxx/xxxx.mp4), but always hang on after runing driver.get(file_url) , then timeout after 300sec(firefox default timeout 300 sec),  the mp4 file has downloaded ,but driver.get(file_url) no response so i can't close firefox! 
i have try file_url is normal web like http://www.google.com ,the response is ok!

can anybody help?

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', path)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'video/mp4')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get(file_url)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `get` for this because you don't want a get to timeout. What you want is to create a link element at run-time using javascript and then click on it to perform the download

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', "/tmp")
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'video/mp4')
profile.set_preference('media.mp4.enabled', False)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get("http://www.google.com")

driver.execute_script("""
elem = document.createElement("a");
elem.id = "__download__";
elem.href = "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4";
elem.text = "__download__";
elem.textContent = "__download__content";
parentElem = document.getElementById('viewport');
parentElem.insertBefore(elem, parentElem.firstChild);
""")

driver.find_element_by_id("__download__").click()
```

An extra preference for disabling mp4 was also needed

```
profile.set_preference('media.mp4.enabled', False)
```